# How to add Slack as an Identity Provider in AAD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, slack

I'd like to add Slack as an Identity Provider to my app using AAD B2C. Is there any example of how to build the Technical Profile for that?

I was able to create a Technical profile to connect to Slack, but I'm having a problem with sending a user_scope parameter instead of the scope parameter. The OAuth2 technical profile only supports "scope" parameter and I'm not able to find a way of sending "user_scope" instead.
I was also able to connect using endpoints that didn't include "v2" in them, but I'm not sure that's the right approach

This is the technical profile I'm using in the ClaimsProvider now. I have anothe ClaimsProvider for AAD multitenant. Didn't modify the relying party at all for Slack.

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Slack-OAUTH">
      <DisplayName>Slack</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">slack</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://slack.com/api/users.identity</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">ClientID</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="REFERENCE_TO_SECRET_IN_B2C_KEYS" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="user_scope" DefaultValue="identity.basic" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="slack" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="user" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetIdClaimFromJson" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetNameClaimFromJson" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

The call to slack works and I'm getting a code back and being redirected to aadb2c, but then I get an exception back. Put the policy in development mode to drop logs into App Insights and got an exception saying: An invalid OAuth response was received: '{0}'.
'Message':'The given key was not present in the dictionary.','Data':{}​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable sign-in for users from a Slack account, you need to create a Slack application project.

1. Sign in to the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/apps?new_app=1) with your account credentials.
2. Select **Create New App**.
3. Enter an **App Name** and select a **Development Slack Workspace**.
4. Select **Create App**.
5. Under **App Credentials**, copy the values of **Client ID** and **Client secret**. You will need both of them to configure Slack as an identity provider in your tenant. Client secret is an important security credential.
6. Under **Features**, select **OAuth and Permissions**.
7. Add a new **Redirect URL**, enter `https:/your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`.
   Replace your-tenant-name with the name of your tenant. You need to use all lowercase letters when entering your tenant name even if the tenant is defined with uppercase letters in Azure AD B2C.
8. Click **Save URLs**.

### Create a policy key

You need to store the client secret that you previously recorded in your Azure AD B2C tenant.

1. Sign in to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/).
2. Make sure you're using the directory that contains your Azure AD B2C tenant by clicking the **Directory and subscription filter** in the top menu and choosing the directory that contains your tenant.
3. Choose **All services** in the top-left corner of the Azure portal, and then search for and select **Azure AD B2C**.
4. On the Overview page, select **Identity Experience Framework - PREVIEW**.
5. Select **Policy Keys** and then select **Add**.
6. For **Options**, choose `Manual`.
7. Enter a **Name** for the policy key. For example, `SlackSecret`. The prefix `B2C_1A_` is added automatically to the name of your key.
8. In **Secret**, enter your client secret that you previously recorded.
9. For **Key usage**, select `Signature`.
10. Click **Create**.

Slack claims provider as follows:

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Slack-OAUTH">
    <DisplayName>Log in with your Slack account</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OAuth2"/>
    <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://slack.com/api/oauth.access</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://slack.com/oauth/authorize</Item>
        <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://slack.com/api/users.identity</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">Your Slack App Registration Client ID</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">identity.basic</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_slackfederation"/>
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="slackAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="user" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="slack" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetIdClaimFromJson" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetNameClaimFromJson" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

And supporting claims transforms:

```xml
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetIdClaimFromJson" TransformationMethod="GetClaimFromJson">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="slackOAuthResponse" TransformationClaimType="inputJson" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter Id="claimToExtract" DataType="string" Value="id" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" TransformationClaimType="extractedClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>

    <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetNameClaimFromJson" TransformationMethod="GetClaimFromJson">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="slackOAuthResponse" TransformationClaimType="inputJson" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter Id="claimToExtract" DataType="string" Value="name" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="extractedClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the summary, I was doing that but I'm worried about not using the v2 endpoints that are given in the slack documentation. Is that acceptable? Any official place where that's stated or do you have a justification for it? I'd love to hear it.
Thanks again!

Comment: That i am not sure about, i wrote this up over a year ago and it still works today. `user_scope` is not part of protocol so there will be no metadata item for it. But you can send query parameters by adding them as inputclaims.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. If you happen to have an example on how to do the input claim thing, I'd really appreciate it. I tried to do it but the policy wouldn't pass the validation when uploading it.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a complete TrustFrameworkExtensions file with slack working? I'm having exceptions and can't figure out which of all the errors I should tackle. For example I'm getting: AADB2C: A claim with id 'issuerUserId' was not found, which is required by ClaimsTransformation 'CreateAlternativeSecurityId'

Comment: In my answer, replace all instances of socialIdpUserId with issuerUserId.

Comment: Is there a way here to open a chat to iron out a few details? If you have the time of course.
I was able to make it work even with the new OAuth Slack APIs v2, but anyway I'm getting: An invalid OAuth response was received: "{0}".
The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question with some more description of the new error. Thanks for sticking around :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this same situation where user_scope isn't a valid parameter in my .net core web app.

I tried setting the auth endpoint to:

https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?user_scope=identity.basic+identity.email+identity.team

and that did get past one hurdle, but after I sign in and am redirected back to my web app, it fails to process the claims. I'll update this partial answer if I can get it working, but hopefully, it will help someone figure this out.